# What is the difference between <T> and <T : Any>

Tags: kotlin, generics

In Kotlin, what is there difference between the following two functions:

```
fun<T> List<T>.myFunction() { ...
fun<T : Any> List<T>.myOtherFunction() { ...
```

Presumably this `Any` constraint is there for a reason, but what is it?

Comment: `<T>` translates to `<T : Any?>`. If you write it your ide will probably suggest to remove it as it's redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**<`T>`:**  Without any constraints, it can be any type, including nullable types (e.g., T?), platform types, and non-nullable types

**`<T : Any>`:** Must be a non-nullable type. It excludes nullable types and platform types, ensuring that T is a concrete, non-nullable type.